# Cannot open The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy bluray

Tags: 14.04, mount, cd-ripping, blu-ray

I am having trouble opening The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy bluray on Xubuntu 14.04. I am able to open other encrypted bluray discs just fine and rip them with MakeMKV. This specific disc is the only one, so far, that I cannot seem to open. The disc itself is in perfect condition and plays in my set top bluray player with no issues.

`mount /dev/sr0 /media/bluray` returns `mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0`. I get the same response when using `mount -t udf` as well.

`dmesg | grep sr0` returns:

```
[    0.916490] sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 40x/40x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    0.916575] sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
```

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!